# Is there a way to get notification on iphone when i get any answer or comment on my question?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, notifications, iphone

Is there any app or trick to get notification upon answer or comment on my question, on my iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting a question you can specify whether or not to be notified via email; this is no longer (not sure it ever was) a per-question setting, but applies to the way Stack Overflow will notify you in general (in fact, the link on the question asking page just expands your Stack Exchange notification box, where the settings can otherwise be accessed manually).

This gives you numerous options: you can receive unread notifications *three-hourly*, *daily*, or *weekly*. Your iPhone can surely then access your emails.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't get any mails upon getting answer or comment. How i can get email instantly if some give an answer or comment on my every question

Comment: No, by default SE don't bombard you with emails, and I'm glad.

Comment: Ok How can i save this setting once for my all questions. I don't want to set it for each time

Comment: @Jitendra The settings shown in the last screenshot are for all the questions.